# Add-on not visible in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I'm new to google app script. I have configured my add-on. I cannot open the add-on once the user has already opened it.

Suppose i have opened the add-on. Now I'm again going to open it then it shows the "**content not available for this message**". I have attached the **image**.
My code is below:
[image: Addon Image]
appscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Test Addon",
      "logoUrl": "https://test/add-on_logo-32x32.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
      },
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "showSidebar"
      }
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "showSidebar"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Macro.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('home');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}

function showSidebar() {
    
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('login').evaluate().setTitle("test Add-on")
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}

function goToHome(token) {
  const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('API_TOKEN', token);
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('home').evaluate().setTitle("test Add-on")
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);

}
```

**Can anyone tell me when I have made a mistake?**

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `addOns` key in the manifest (appscript.json), and the associated trigger functions only work with the CardService based UI.

I have built a similar application with a smaller appscript.json (for Slides):

```js
{
  "timeZone": "Etc/UTC",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

and the (slightly redacted) `Code.gs` contents:

```js
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('App')
      .addItem('Open App', 'openApp')
      .addToUi();
}

function openApp(){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('app'); // open app.html
  var userToken = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('USER_TOKEN');
  if(userToken){
    html.token = '?token='+userToken;
  }
  else{
    html.token = '';
  }

  SlidesApp.getUi() 
    .showSidebar(html.evaluate().setTitle('App'));
}
```

This works fine to open from the menu in Google Slides, but before going this route I also spent a lot of time attempting to use the triggerFunctions and the `addOns` key in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will work fine in Google Slides. I want to fix the issue in Google Sheets. So is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please look into this? I'm not confirming but maybe we need to pass this macro option for the sheet. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros#manifest_structure_for_macros
Am i right?